# ¿Puedo rellenar un ArrayList de un tipo con un ArrayList de otro en Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Soy novato en Java y ahora estoy estudiando el tema de los Arraylist.

He leido que un Arraylist solo puede contener elementos objeto del mismo tipo que el objeto Arraylist, pero ¿hay alguna forma de meter un Arrayliste de un tipo dentro de otro Arraylist de otro tipo?

Pongo código de ejemplo:

**Clase Vehiculo:**

```
public class Vehiculo {

    private int plazasPasajeros;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;


    public Vehiculo(int plazasPasajeros, String marca, String modelo) {
        this.plazasPasajeros = plazasPasajeros;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;

    }
}
```

**Clase Pasajero:**

```
public class Pasajero {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;


    public Pasajero(String nombre, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

**Principal:**

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Vehiculo>vehiculos=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Pasajero>pasajeros=new ArrayList<>();


        Vehiculo vehiculo1 = new Vehiculo(5,"Seat","Toledo");
        Vehiculo vehiculo2 = new Vehiculo(5,"Renault","Laguna");

        Pasajero pasajero1 = new Pasajero("Sebastián",25);
        Pasajero pasajero2 = new Pasajero("Antonio",43);
        Pasajero pasajero3 = new Pasajero("Ruben",38);
        Pasajero pasajero4 = new Pasajero("Laia",19);
        Pasajero pasajero5 = new Pasajero("Raquel",28);
        Pasajero pasajero6 = new Pasajero("Gerard",43);
        Pasajero pasajero7 = new Pasajero("Lola",32);
        Pasajero pasajero8 = new Pasajero("Paco",54);


   }
}
```

Bien...como véis tengo una clase Vehiculo y otra Pasajero, ambas con sus respectivos atributos y su constructor, y en la clase Principal he construido dos objetos "vehiculo" y ocho objetos "pasajero".También tengo un Arraylist vehiculo y otro pasajero.

El tema es, ¿Puedo rellenar el ArrayList de objetos pasajero y después ese ArrayList meterlo dentro del ArrayList vehiculo para poder manipular los datos desde ahí?¿Existe esa posibilidad?`

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregar un `ArrayList` como miembro de la clase `Vehiculo`:

```
public class Vehiculo {

    private int plazasPasajeros;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private ArrayList<Pasajero> pasajeros;


    public Vehiculo(int plazasPasajeros, String marca, String modelo, ArrayList<Pasajero> pasajeros) {
        this.plazasPasajeros = plazasPasajeros;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.pasajeros = pasajeros;
    }
}
```

Así al crear una instancia de la clase `Vehiculo` le pasas el `ArrayList` con los pasajeros.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes meter objetos de tipo `Vehículo` en un `ArrayList<Pasajero>`, y viceversa.
Sí puedes meter ambos en un `ArrayList<Object>`, o en un `ArrayList<T>`, siendo T una clase o interfaz que extiendan o implementen ambas clases(por eso funciona con `Object`, ya que todas las clases son subclases de `Object`).